# Question on Homotopy and Homology Groups of Spaces $X$ and $X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I have a general question about the differnce of homology and (simplicial) homotopy groups
of a topological space in degrees $X$ and the space $Y := X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$ obtained by glueing
$D^n$-ball to $X$ along continuous boundary map $f: S^{n-1} \to X$ and obtain in that way the new space $Y:= X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$.

What can we say about the change of homotopy and homology groups of degree $0 \le k <n$?
I conjecture that for these $k$ the answer should be that homotopy and homology doesn't
change, ie $\pi_k(X)= \pi_k(Y)$ and $H^k(X, \mathbb{Z})= H^k(Y, \mathbb{Z})$ but
I would like to know I a 'geometrical' argument for it. Now I would like to present my efforts and I would be thankful if somebody could give feedback if my arguments work:

1. What I tried on $\pi_k(Y)$ : Let $[s] \in [S^k, Y]$ and we have to show that $[s]$ is homotopy
   equivalent to a map $S^k \to X$. Choose a representant $s: S^k \to Y=  X \cap_{S^{n-1}} D^n$
   and compose it with collapse map $c:X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n \to S^n$ which collapses $X$ to a
   point. By Sard's theorem the composition of $s$ with $c$ cannot be surjective, therefore
   there exist a point $p \in S^n$ with hasn't a preimage and $c \circ s$ factorizes over
   $S^n \backslash p \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$.

So we conclude that $c \circ s$ is hotopic to m map which factorizes over contractable space
$\mathbb{R}^n$, and therefore $c \circ s$ should be homotopic to constant map, right?

2. About homology: We can always assume that $X$ is a CW-complex and let
   $C^X_m \to C^X_{m-1} \to ... \to C^X_k \to ... \to C^X_1$ it's cell complex
   with differentials $d_i^X: C^X_i \to C^X_{i-1}$ described in every book on algebraic topology and where
   $C^X _i = \bigoplus_{c_i \text{ i-cell }} \mathbb{Z} \cdot c_i $. The resolution
   of $Y$ differs from that one of $X$ only by an additional $n$-cell, ie
   $C^Y_i = C^X_i$ for $i \neq n$ and $C^Y_n = C^X_n \oplus \mathbb{Z} \cdot c_n$. Making this
   identification between $i$-cells and using the canonical
   inclusion map $C^X_n \subset C^Y_n$ we obtain a map between chain complexes of $X$ and $Y$.
   The $i$-th homology is by definition $H^i()=ker(d_i)/im(d_{i+1})$. For all $i < n -1$ we have equal
   differentials $d^X_i=d^Y_i$ by construction of our cell complexes $X$ and $Y$, the $d^X_n $
   and $d^Y_n$.

So I think that from this we can always conclude $H^i(X) = H^i(Y)$ for $ i < n-2$, right?
Up to now, are my reasonings correct?
If yes, then similary, $H^i(X) = H^i(Y)$ for $i >n$, as $C^X_n \subset C^Y_n$ is injective.
About $i = n, n-1$ in general we cannot say anything.

Are my 'proofs' 1 and 2 ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this will be heavily dependent on your choice of map $f$, as well as the dimension of $D^n$. For example, say $X$ is a circle, so $\pi_1(X)\simeq\mathbb{Z}$, and all higher homotopy groups vanish.

Now, let $Y$ be obtained from $X$ by attaching a $2$-cell by a map of degree $k$. Van Kampen's theorem asserts that the fundamental group of $Y$ is now cyclic of order $k$, and now the higher homotopy groups need not vanish (e.g. $k=2$ yields $\mathbb{R}P^2$). However, if instead we attach the $2$-cell via a constant map, then $Y$ is now $S^1\wedge S^2$, which also has different homotopy groups than $X$.

You can find more examples in Chapter 4 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, available for free in his own website.

P.D.: although I didn't mention homology in my answer, you can also see that (in the second example) letting $f$ be a constant map adds a $2$-cycle that wasn't there before, so the homologies also differ.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From your example I see
that in general attatching a ball $D^n$ to a space could
change to *homotopy groups* $\pi_k$ between 
$\pi(X)$ and $\pi(X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n)$ in a highly 
nontrivial way *in all degrees $k$' , that's the massage? 
Originally, I hoped that there is some valid statement 
which depends only on $n$ but not of $f: S^{n-1} \to X$, ie 
something like 'if we glue $D^n$ to $X$ then for all $k < k_0(n)$ (ie $k_0(n)$ depends on $n$) the 
homotopy groups $\pi_k(-)$ of $X$ and $X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$
coinside, but for

Comment: higher $k$ we pay the price so 
we have no control.' But as far as I understand your examples
correctly, then for every $n$ (which we might fix at the beginning) a choice of glueing map 
$f: S^{n-1} \to X$ could lead to the case that *all*
$k$-homotopy groups change, right?

Comment: But concerning the (cellular) homology groups I'm a
bit more optimistic, since although we have to track
the glueing map $f: S^{n-1} \to X$ carefully, I conjecture
that the changing effect of glueing $D^n$ to $X$ concern at most
the homology groups $H^i $ with $i= n, n+1$,  while 
other homology groups not change, or is
the story with homology also so complicated like in case
of homotopy, which you sketched? The reason why I think that in case of homology the groups
$H_i$ with $i \neq n, n+1$ for $X$ and 
$X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$ should coincide, is that

Comment: if we 
wlog take $X$ to be CW with cell complex
$C^X_m \to   ... \to C^X_1 \to C^X_0$ then the cell complex
of $X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$ differs from that one of $X$ only
in degree $i=n$, so the only differentials which differ
are these in degrees $n $ and $n+1$. So here it seems that
different glueing maps $f$ could only affect 
a difference of differentials in $n+1$ and $n$ degrees, 
other doesn't change, or not?
nd therefore homology should coincide in other degrees, or
am I wrong?

Comment: You can actually argue in a similar way for homotopy groups: indeed, if you attach cells of high enough dimension, the lower homotopy groups will not change. For example, attaching a $3$-cell or higher to a space will not change it's fundamental group (this is due to the Cellular Approximation theorem), so there is some flexibility on how to glue $n$-cells.

Comment: So my approach on homology groups is correct? ie if
$Y= X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n$ then, independently how crazy
the attatching map $f: S^{n-1} \to X$ is, the *homology*
groups $H_k(X)$ and $H_k(Y)$ differ *only* in degrees $n$ and $n+1$,
right?

Comment: And in your last comment you probably refer also to this point
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_approximation_theorem#Cellular_approximation_for_pairs

which is a consequence of CAT, ie that if the pair $(X, X^n)$ is $n$-connected, 
then for all $i <n$ the homotopy groups $\pi_i(X^n)$ and 
$\pi_i(X)$ coinside. Then if $X$ is a complex with cell smaller then $n$, then
then pair $(X, X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n)$ satisfies 
$\pi_i(X) = \pi_i(X \cup_{S^{n-1}} D^n)$ for all $i < n-1$?

That's the point you intended to stress?